# uploading a text file by clicking a browse button

Tags: robotframework

I am writing robot tests for web testing using Robot Framework with SeleniumLibrary (a test library) , one of my test involves uploading a file from the desktop by clicking on a"Browse" button on the webpage and using the windows file explorer window that pops up to navigate to and select the file. I have downloaded Autolt library but not able to figure it out which keyword is to be used.Any sample testcase is more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Choose File`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Choose%20File) should work the way you want.

If that doesn't work, try [`Press Keys`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Keys) to directly type the path to your input.

Comment: All are broken links.